# How to specify ContentType for Web API controller method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

There's a Request object, and getting the request content type is easy. But how do you *specify* a content type for the response? My controller looks like this (other actions excised for brevity):

```
public class AuditController : ApiController
{   
  // GET api/Audit/CSV
  [HttpGet, ActionName("CSV")]
  public string Csv(Guid sessionId, DateTime a, DateTime b, string predicate)
  {
    var result = new StringBuilder();
    //build a string
    return result.ToString();
  }
}
```

This works fine except that it has the wrong content type. I'd like to do this

```
Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
```

A little research reveals that we can type the Action to return an HttpResponseMessage. So the end of my method would look like this:

```
  var response = new HttpResponseMessage() ;
  response.Headers.Add("ContentType","text/csv");
  response.Content = //not sure how to set this
  return response;
```

The documentation on HttpContent is rather sparse, can anyone advise me on how to get the contents of my StringBuilder into an HttpContent object?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You'll have to change the return type of the method to `HttpResponseMessage`, then use `Request.CreateResponse`:

```
// GET api/Audit/CSV
[HttpGet, ActionName("CSV")]
public HttpResponseMessage Csv(Guid sessionId, DateTime a, DateTime b, string predicate)
{
    var result = new StringBuilder();

    //build a string

    var res = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    res.Content = new StringContent(result.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "text/csv");

    return res;
}
```

Comment: Aha! It was the use of Request.CreateResponse that I needed. Points are all your! (Just looked at MediaTypeFormatter... why would anyone make it so complicated?)

Comment: You can leave out "yet"... I'm getting `Could not find a formatter matching the media type 'text/csv' that can write an instance of 'String'.` which tells me I need to put my *build a string* logic into a MediaTypeFormatter and associate it with text/csv, and pass the LINQ result to it via CreateResponse. Thanks for getting me over the hump there.

Comment: This worked for me when I needed to return `"text/xml"`.  Side Note: Twilio webhooks would not handle Parameterization in my `ApiController`, so I either had to use `FormDataCollection` (then foreach through that for Parameters) or switch from `ApiController` back to `Controller`, for my named Parameters in the Method's signature to be populated by Twilio.  I went with the latter (non-WebApi) and use this instead: `return Content(result.ToString(), "text/xml")`

Answer (score 3):

**You do not want to return `HttpResponseMessage`** as that returns the response your own Controller Method got from calling a second server's API for data. It just packages up that response into JSON and sends that to your caller. Bad idea!

ASP.NET Core in 2023 has updated the Response Types for Web API and MVC. They have updated the `IActionResult` type and many subtypes derived from it, including some simpler "helper functions" that wrap the content, content-type, and status code into one Response call. They all allow *customizations* before sending out the Response. So let's use your `text/csv` mime-type example, and create one...

This first one is simpler, and allows you to customize the content-type. `ContentResult` is like `JsonResult`. Both are specialized for specific data types. `ContentResult` is used more for `text` content using the `text/plain` mime-type delivered in the response. But you can actually change it to deliver other types...

```
        [HttpGet("[action]")]
        public ContentResult MyCSV()
        {
            return new ContentResult
            {
                Content = "a,b,c",
                ContentType = "text/csv",
                StatusCode = 200
            };
        }
```

This second one is more complex, but allows you to use the raw response object to encode your string, set the content-type and status code, and stream it out to the caller...

```
        [HttpGet("[action]")]
        public async Task MyCSV()
        {
            var mystring = "a,b,c;
            byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(mystring);
            this.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
            this.Response.StatusCode = 200;
            await Response.Body.WriteAsync(data,0,data.Length);
        }
```