# Return self-created JSON from Web API Controller using CreatedAtAction without escaping?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, stored-procedures

Is it possible to return self-created JSON from an controller action method, so that it is not additionally escaped by ASP Net Core?

Consider the following code:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[Produces("application/json")]
public class MyController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<string>> Post(ItemPostRequest itemPostRequest)
    {
        var result = await callStoredProcedureOnDatabase(itemPostRequest); // generates JSON directly on the database using SQL Server's FOR JSON clause

        return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetItem),
            new { Id = result.Id },
            result.Json
            );
    }
}
```

- If I remove the third line with `[Produces("application/json")]` I get the unescaped JSON as expected, but the Content-Type header is only set to `text/plain`.
- If I leave the `[Produces("application/json")]` in place, the Content-Type is correctly set to `application/json`, but my JSON become escaped.

So, how can I return the `result.Json` without getting escaped while having a correct Content-Type header of `application/json`?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do something like the answer here: [How to specify ContentType for Web API controller method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23381309/how-to-specify-contenttype-for-web-api-controller-method)

The producers attribute, forced the format to be json. JSon strings are escaped correctly, so the result us expected. Beware that all clients expect a specific format, so if you are returning json, it is suggested that you remove the escape characters. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-5.0

> The preceding [Produces] filter:
>
> - Forces all actions within the controller to return JSON-formatted responses.
> - If other formatters are configured and the client specifies a different format, JSON is returned.